# SQL-Calculate price for how long one used an item- monthly price, weekly price, and hourly price

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

let's say we are renting out a bike. There's a monthly($100), weekly($10), and hourly($1) price. If I used it for 1 month, 2 weeks, and 4 hours, the price would be $124. I have a while loop that will do the modulus to see if the hours is longer than monthly and weekly and add to the price and subtract the duration of the borrowed item.

```
SET @dateDiff =   DATEDIFF(hour,@TimeIn,@TimeOut); 
-- 7 days is 168 hours
-- 30 days is 720 hour

WHILE  @bool != 1  
    BEGIN  

    IF (@dateDiff > 720)
        SET  @totalPrice += (@dateDiff%720) * @monthlyPrice
        SET @dateDiff = @dateDiff - (@dateDiff%720)
    ELSE IF  (@dateDiff > 168)
        SET  @totalPrice += (@dateDiff%168) * @weeklyPrice
        SET @dateDiff = @dateDiff - (@dateDiff%168)
    ELSE
        SET  @totalPrice += @dateDiff * @weeklyPrice
        SET @bool = 1;
END
```

I want to do something like above.

Comment: @DaleBurrell my while statement is failing. Can't do ELSE if statements

Comment: Define what you mean by a month. If I use a bike from 28th February to 31st March, how long is that? If it's 1 month and 3 days, then renting a bike in Feb costs more than renting one in March...

Comment: @MatBailie for now a month is 30 days which is 720 hours

Comment: If you look at the SQL Server online reference it tells you how to do all that. Primarily you need to use `begin` and `end` for multi-line `if/then` statements.

Comment: Did a month really cost the same as 10 weeks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @months = @datediff / 720
SET @weeks = (@datediff % 720) / 168
SET @hours = (@datediff % 720) % 168
```

No loop required

Comment: Or in one statement: `select @months = @datediff / 720, @weeks = (@datediff % 720) / 168, @hours = (@datediff % 720) % 168;`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `@TimeIn` and `@TimeOut` directly without calucate the hours first, in this case `@Start` and `@End` represent `@TimeIn` and `@TimeOut`

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME = '2018-01-01 01:00:00';
DECLARE @End   DATETIME = '2018-02-14 04:00:00';

SELECT FORMAT(
       DATEDIFF(Month, @Start, @End) * 100 + --Months
       DATEDIFF(Week, @Start, DATEADD(Month, -DATEDIFF(Month, @Start, @End), @End)) * 10 + --Weeks
       DATEDIFF(Hour, @Start, DATEADD(Day, -DATEDIFF(Day, @Start, @End), @End)) --Hours
       , 'C'
       , 'en-us'
       ) AS ClientShouldPay;
```

Results:

```
+-----------------+
| ClientShouldPay |
+-----------------+
| $123.00         |
+-----------------+
```

Note: **[`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples)** funtion avaliable only on 2012+, you can remove it if you want to.

Comment: The op confirmed that a month is 30 days, not a calendar month. Which is important in pricing, so that February isn't more expensive per day than March (for example)

Comment: @MatBailie Even so, that's wrong a _Month_ can't be always 30 days.

Comment: Then you're missing the point.  It's not a CALENDAR month.  It's a regularly occurring period of time that *approximates* a month.  Billing of this kind rarely uses calendar months ***because*** a calendar month varies in length.  Where calendar months ***are*** used, the billing amount normally varies by the the month length.  In this case the op has specifically stated that a "month" for billing purposes is exactly and always 30 days, this allows a fixed and unvarying "monthly" charge to be used.

Comment: +1.. I don't see this is bad answer.. Just not fitting  with the op want.. I hope it will help the future reader not see month = 30